# (Luatex makes) newtx superscript number font different from text number

Tags: fonts, luatex, superscripts, newtx

The `newtx` package somehow uses a font with noticeably greater weight for superscript (footnote) numbers. How can I force it to use the same one as in the text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\begin{document}

1\footnote{}
2\footnote{}
3\footnote{}
4\footnote{}
5\footnote{}
6\footnote{}
7\footnote{}
8\footnote{}
9\footnote{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** I've found that I got the expected result using PdfTex instead of Lualatex. I'm leaving this up just in case someone knows why and the way to make it work with Lualatex if one exists.

[image]

Comment: Your rendering looks a bit suspect, with texlive 2021 [I get this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH7Ad.png) with xpdf rendering

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your looks much better. I use Miktex, but that shouldn't matter, should it? The output is the same for me on both Sumatra and PDF-XChange.

Comment: Same result with Vivaldi and Edge browsers.

Comment: newtx loads the realscripts package. That changes the footnote markers.